# Using SQL DSN With SubSonic

Tags: sql, subsonic, data-access-layer, dsn

I want to create a SQL connection using DSN. Then I want to generate the DAL using Subsonic. Please can you give me some pointers on what to do?

Comment: Have you tried the demos from http://subsonicproject.com/?  Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a DSN in these days (I assume you want to abstract the connection) - you can do that with SubSonic 3 by specifying the provider right in the connection string. If you want to switch providers, just change the "providerName" attribute of the connectionString.

I'm wondering if this is for legacy issues but a DSN is entirely in your control, it seems - and I think there's a better way.